# JMeter SubNet issue

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

How does JMeter determine what subnet it is on ?? I don't see a subnetMask property in the jmeter property file.

My client is on x.y.76.54, my server is on x.y.77.75. The subnet mask is 255.255.254.0

Technically, these two IPs are on the same subnet. I am seeing a "connection refused" response from the Server. Firewalls are off. Should JMeter be able to handle the ip's as provided above ?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter relies on your **operating system network settings**, given both hosts are able to "see" each other - JMeter will be able to do this as well.

Your setup assumes hosts from `x.y.76.1` to `x.y.77.254` so it's a valid use case, you can double check it using i.e. [Online IP Subnet Calculator](http://www.subnet-calculator.com/)

It's hard to say what exactly is wrong without seeing how you're launching JMeter master and slave and [log files for both](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), [RMI properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote) like `client.rmi.localport`, `server.rmi.localport`, [java.rmi.server.hostname property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/javarmiproperties.html), etc.

It might also be the case JMeter is trying to use IPv6 addresses so it might worth trying setting [`java.net.preferIPv4Stack` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html) to `true`

See [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter) article for more details and if you will be still experiencing problems consider providing more information on the above points.

Comment: I used wireshark to snarf the transaction. IPv4 definitely used. I will continue to dig. thanks

Comment: @Dmitri T can you please look into the following problem and let me know if this solution is possible or not ... its a humble request : https://stackoverflow.com/q/63053225/3928743